# Передвижение игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Пишу 2d top down шутер на Unity 2017.1 C#.
2 дня как пытаюсь реализовать движение игрока по курсору.
Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMove : MonoBehaviour {

    void FixedUpdate () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }
}
```

Этот код выводит ошибки..

```
Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs(8,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector2)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs(8,46): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `float' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector2'
Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs(9,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector2)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/Scripts/playerMove.cs(9,46): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `float' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector2'
```

Что делать?

Comment: Читать хотя бы документацию для начала, миллион и один тутор для новичков и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `AddForce()` принимает аргументом тип `Vector2`, а вы ему даете на вход результат функции `Input.GetAxis()`, которая возвращает float.

Правильней будет так :

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде получилось(ошибок нет), но игрок не двигается, теперь  надо риг настроить в инспекторе?

Comment: Вы получили вектор, теперь нужно копать в сторону forward

Comment: Код "убийца CPU"... @BBann Естественно не будет двигаться, из курса школьной физики сила измеряется в ньютонах, вы объекту добавляете силу, а getAxis возращает значения от -1 до 1. То есть вы добавляете силу в 1 ньютон, а этого может оказаться не достаточно для преодоления сил трения и прочее. В Vector2 по сути кладется только направление, его бы еще нормализовать. И вот это направление можно уже умножать на силу, а сколько ее нужно приложить зависит от многих факторов, которые также можно узнать из курса школьной физики.